# How to secure the logout route of FOSUserBundle

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle

For my application, I need to deactivate the access of the logout route of FOSUserBundle for certain users, but when I add the access control, it doesn't work anyway.

Somebody can help me with this feature ?

EDIT : my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
 
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_PRO_AGENT: ROLE_PRO_USER
        ROLE_PRO_ADMIN: ROLE_PRO_AGENT
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_API: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_API, ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_PRO_ADMIN]
 
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
 
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path:     fos_user_security_login
                check_path:     fos_user_security_check
                default_target_path: espace_perso
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                failure_path: fos_user_security_login
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: fos_user_security_login
            anonymous: true
             
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/%locale%/logout, roles: [ ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/test/.*, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/essai, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/create-user-temp, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/delete-user-temp, role: ROLE_ADMIN, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/login, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/login_check, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/register, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/%locale%/resetting, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF ] }
        - { path: ^/coulisse, roles: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN ] }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: [ ROLE_API ] }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF }
```

Comment: Post here your config for security component.

Comment: Thanks, posted in the EDIT section :)

Comment: Assume that you have role `ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF` and if you click `logout` you are still logged in? And you can click `logout` as many times as you want?

Comment: No, users that I want to not allow access to 'logout' have role 'ROLE_USER_TEMP' and don't have role 'ROLE_USER_DEFINITIF'. Excuse me if I did not be precise. The problem is that when my user have the role 'ROLE_USER_TEMP', he still can access the 'logout' route.